# Job search for Europe seems to have broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

A couple of weeks ago, I could type "Europe" in the location box and only European jobs returned.

Lately, it appears to completely ignore that criteria and returns all locations. 
[image]
I even have a saved Europe search that seems to have stopped working.
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=Javascript&l=Europe&u=Miles&d=20&ss=1&sort=p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We made a recent change to fix an issue with Northern Ireland not being resolved to an ISO country code correctly and we inadvertently introduced a regression for anything less granular than country resolution.

Fix is building out to production now. Apologies for the inconvenience!